# How to (re)enable IntelliJ IDEA alt-enter log support

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA has a nice litte feature which allows to create unique LOG IDs for your log output.

It is simply used by typing **Alt-Enter** and then choose **Add-LogID**.

But I did it again. A slip of a finger and instead of **Add-LogID** I clicked **Disable**. Now the feature gone. Disappeared. Can't find it any more.

Does anybody know how to re-enable the it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't provide such intention out of the box, most likely you are using the third-party [Log Support](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=4953) plug-in. Double check that it's still installed and enabled, then turn on this intention:

[image]

Comment: “intention” — Ahh, once you know what to look for it becomes all easy. For a German “alt-enter” = “Intension” was not apparent hence I looked at the wrong places and used the wrong search box. Thanks for the help.